# How to avoid Silverlight ugly fonts?

Tags: silverlight

I'd like to show some client that Silverlight can be used as a technology for BL apps.
 They were shocked that some firm waste the money for so crappy looking technology (it's about MS)...

I just presented a screen with a few TextBoxes and some other controls...

Any size of the font in pixels or pts I use (or TextHintingMode), with embedding the font as a resource (or not) - the result is all the time very poor. **It looks really crappy !!!**

Is it possible that after four versions of Silverlight Microsoft doesn't know how to render some text looking readable?

Or maybe I just don't know how to prepare TextBox with sharp and clear Tahoma font.
Any ideas?

Magnified sample from client's TextBox is below:
[image: Magnified result from TextBox]

Comment: I was trying different fonts. This one sample comes from Tahoma or MS Serif font tests...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look the following article:
http://10rem.net/blog/2010/06/06/wpf-and-silverlight-choose-your-fonts-and-text-rendering-options-wisely

The font you're using may not be optimized for the size you're displaying it at.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...

I have seen this article already ;(

New WPF (version 4) has many improvements on font's rendering, SL not ;(

The issue/question is how to display clear text in SL using fonts like Tahoma...

Some info about crappy text rendering in SL is here also:

http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1016